siunitx issue when using angle-mode=arc with negative numbers
I've been having two issues with siunitx that I was hoping someone might be able to help out with:

When getting it to convert an angle in decimals to arc mode using the [angle-mode=arc] modifier, the document doesn't want to compile if the number is negative.

When rounding in arc mode, zeros are added in front of the minutes and seconds as opposed to only rounding of the last decimal place of seconds


Any ideas on how to get around these issues?
Here's the MWE for showing how it doesn't handle negative numbers:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\ang[angle-mode=arc]{-2.03}

\end{document}

And here's an MWE showing the rounding-off issue (I've set the angle to a positive one in this MWE so that it doesn't crash):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{round-mode = places, round-precision = 3}

\begin{document}

\ang[angle-mode=arc]{2.03} 

\end{document}


First thing is a bug, second is an edge case where the 'right' outcome is not immediately clear - I'll need to think

I may be a few days but I will look over the code for both issues

https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/743 and https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/744

The conversion of negative angles to arcs had not been properly addressed. I have updated the code to do that, and will release it as v3.3.21. The changes needed are in a few places, so unless it's super-urgent, I recommend waiting for the TeX Live/MiKTeX update to install rather than trying to in-place patch.
The second issue is more nuanced but I will add some suppression there: the internal is a bit long so a refactor will go along with this, and thus again best to wait for the update.

Thank you so much, Joseph. It isn't urgent, so I'll excitingly wait for the next MikTex update.
